# Disable the suggestions in Search box for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

Is there a way to turn off suggestion in search box?

[image]

Right now it is suggesting folder and documents but I don't want it to show me those suggestion.
I went on my admin center -->search--> Query Suggestion Settings and unchecked the "show search suggestions" but I can still see them. Not sure if I have to wait for certain amount of time or that is not how it is done.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query suggestion settings in the SharePoint Online admin center is for classic search.

I don't think it's possible to disable query suggestions in the modern search.